# Msg 102, Level 15

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
create procedure sp_AD_CAREOF_COL
(
    @tablename as varchar(200), 
    @column as varchar(200), 
    @column2 as varchar(200)
)

As
    if col_length(@tablename, @column) is null
    begin
        alter table auto
        add careof varchar(200)
        print ('the care of column is added')
    end
    else if COL_LENGTH(@tablename,@column2) is null
    begin
        alter table auto
        add ACCTG_CAREof varchar(200)
        print 'the ACCTG_CAREOF column are added'
    end
    else
    begin
        print'BOTH COLUMN ARE PRESENT'
    end

exec sp_AD_CAREOF_COL ('auto','careof','acctg_careof');
```

While using this code I got the msg 102 error anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Message 102 means incorrect syntax. Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Please don't use an [`sp_` prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments): "Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name.". That advice has existed for **decades**.

Comment: Stop and think about your code. Why does it have parameters that represent table and column names? And why does your code ignore those parameters with alter statements where the table and column names are hard-coded? "Print" is generally not how a procedure should communicate with an application. Start over.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`EXEC` command is wrong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters), use the following instead (remove `(` and `)`):

```
EXEC sp_AD_CAREOF_COL 'auto', 'careof', 'acctg_careof';
```

You can also use the following:

```
EXEC sp_AD_CAREOF_COL @tablename = 'auto', @column = 'careof', @column2 = 'acctg_careof'
```